# Autowired property not working, but autowired setter is?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean class in a Spring 3.2.2 project:

```
@Service
public class PropertyFacade {

//  This DOES NOT work
    @Autowired
    private String propertyFileName;

//  This DOES work
//    @Autowired
//    public void setPropertyFileName( String propertyFileName ) {
//        this.propertyFileName = propertyFileName;
//    }
```

My spring config file has the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.sperbolink.utility" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.sperbolink.facade" />

<bean id="propertyFacade" class="org.sperbolink.facade.PropertyFacade" >
    <property name="propertyFileName" value="test-properties.inf" />
</bean>
```

And my calling method looks like:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "spring-config-test.xml" );
    BeanFactory factory = classPathXmlApplicationContext;
    PropertyFacade propertyFacade = ( PropertyFacade ) factory.getBean( "propertyFacade" );
```

For some reason, when I try to autowire the property, I get an error:

```
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String org.sperbolink.facade.PropertyFacade.propertyFileName; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

But, when I autowire the setter, everything works fine.  Why doesn't the property autowiring work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception message tells you *exactly* what the problem is:

You don't have `propertyFileName` bean defined any where.
You just have *property* `propertyFileName` defined inside *bean* `propertyFacade`. This won't work if you have no setter.

With your setup, `propertyFileName` value `test-properties.inf` will be injected *automatically* into the appropriate field in `propertyFacade` class. No `@Autowire` annotation is needed here.

`@Autowire` with fields can be used when you want to inject a (somewhere defined) `<bean>` into a particular field. This shouldn't be mixed with using `<property>`.

Read more in [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).

Comment: Only if the setter is un-commented. `<property>` requires a setter.

Comment: Another option is constructor injection, which can be either autowired or specified in the bean configuration:  <bean id="propertyFileName" class="java.lang.String"><constructor-arg value="test-properties.inf" /></bean>.  This can of course also be applied to the propertyFacade to enable you to create a class with a real, usable constructor that you can use for testing, but can also use within a CDI container

Answer (score 0):

You can not autowire String and primitive values. Spring does not support that. That is why field based autowiring is not working

When you uncomment property based autowiring  you immediately override it with XML config where you inject a particular value - that is why it is working that way.